# zsh: command not found: express even after I have installed both express and express-generator globally

Tags: node.js, shell, express, zsh

Hey so when I try to run express in terminal mac it doesnt work. I already installed express-generator and express using sudo npm install -g express and sudo npm install -g express-generator. I was able to find them both in my npm directory. However for some reason, the express command still doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Apparently that directory is not listed in your `$PATH`.

Comment: How would i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the fix! For some reason, I was in the interactive shell for zsh without even knowing it all this time. I don't even remember when it changed. All I needed to do was do bash -l and go to my bash login shell. Now everything works!